# NPM Multer, alternative to onFileUploadComplete

Tags: node.js, mongoose, multer

I'm trying to save form information into a mongoose db along with uploading a file. I have tried various examples but it seems like the 'onFileUploadComplete' opt has been removed. Here is the code below:

```
router.post('/info', function(req, res, next){
    multer({ storage:
        multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function(req, file, callback){
                var path = "./public/assets";   
                switch(req.body.type)
                {
                    case 'link': path += '/link'; break;
                    case 'PDF': path += '/PDF'; break;
                    case 'video': path += '/video'; break;
                    case 'audio': path += '/audio'; break;
                    case 'image': path += '/image/' + req.body.folder; break;
                }
                callback(null, path);
            },
            filename: function(req, file, callback){
                callback(null, file.originalname);
            }
        }),
        onFileUploadComplete: function(req, file, callback){
            var asset = new Asset(req.body);
            asset.save(function(err, asset){
                if(err)
                    return next(err);

                return next();
            });
        }
    }).single('file')(req, res, function(err){
        if(err)
            return res.send("Err: "+ err);

        res.render('uploads', {authorised: true});
    });
});
```

Is there an alternative way to upload the file into the designated place, and save the form information (req.body) into a DB.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Readable file stream via `file.stream`. So you could `file.stream.on('end', ...)` to know when the file has finished being *read*. If you want to know if the file has actually finished writing *to disk*, you would need to do something a little more hacky like: `file.stream._readableState.pipes.on('finish', ...)`.

However, if you're wanting to store the `req.body` after the file is complete, why not simply do so in your route handler or perhaps write a custom, generic middleware that wraps the `multer` middleware that does both of these things in a single middleware. For example:

```
function myUpload(multUpload) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    multUpload(req, res, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      // Save `req.body` to database here, then call `next()`
    });
  };
}
```

and use it like:

```
// Here `upload === multer({ ... })`
router.post('/info', myUpload(upload.single('file')), function(req, res, next) {
  if (err)
    return res.send("Err: "+ err);

  res.render('uploads', {authorised: true});
});
```